# How to remove top left window button from ubuntu mate

Tags: window, button, ubuntu-mate

There is a menu button on the top left button that comes in Ubuntu MATE. It gives a drop down option for `minimize` , `maximize`, `close`, etc. options which just takes some extra space in the window. How do I remove this button?

[Something not like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYsIA.png)

but

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15qOv.png)

**Updated :** I just don't want to remove the menu button but I want to save that little space it takes. I want `maximize`, `minimize` and `close` button and `File`, `Edit` menu buttons get merged into same bar like in windows which will ultimately save that unused space

Answer (score 3):

You can use alternative Window Control.

Go to *Control Center* -MATE *Tweak* - *Windows* -*Appearance*.

Change from **Traditional Right** to ***Contemporary Left.***

**If you want to just to remove menu button by keeping Traditional Right layout:**

1) Open dconf Editor.

2) Navigate to org - mate - marco -general

3) Double click on **button-layout**.

4) Change values there, i.e remove **menu** entry from there, but keep colon. Otherwise your menu butttons will go to the left. 
[image]

Comment: I don't mean just to remove top left button but also to save that amount of space for the display. I have 15" screen and saving every centimetre is important for me as to get much more space.  By changing to contemporary left it just removes the button but still takes space.i want somewhat like in windows

Comment: I see, edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you again but I dont just want to remove the menu button. In the screenshot you provided in your answer also, there are 2 text denoting ~dconf editor~. I want to merge those 2 panels. It still takes that little space in the bar

Comment: Maybe switching from Marco to Compiz will help.